# Java: read a TXT file but some content is mistaken

Tags: java

Here are my code:

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
public class Welcome
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
       Scanner in=new Scanner(Paths.get("F:\\myfile.txt"),"UTF-8");
       String sentence=in.nextLine();  // I guess this line of code can read the first line of the txt in to the String sentence?
       System.out.print(sentence);
   }
}
```

and the content of myfile.txt is:

> Eat an apple every day, keep the doctors away!

but the information displayed in the console window is:

[image: content displayed in console window]
Why there was a symbol '?' before normal content?

Thanks! explain as readable as please, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Open your file with a hex Editor and see if there is a non printable character at the beginning of the file

Comment: Maybe it's not UTF-8 file format

Comment: Open the file with a hex editor and look at the first 3 bytes. I'd say you'll see EF BB BF which is the [UTF-8 byte order mark](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) (unless your file isn't encoded as UTF-8).

Comment: This is most likely a IDE related issue 

I am guessing the ? is the cursor of the line for your IDE, or your operating system.

This code works just fine in NetBeans8.2 and TextPad8 with Java8 Loaded.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I just found what the problem is.

Comment: the file was encoded in UTF-8 with BOM, so there was a mistake in the console window, I remove the BOM , then the program works well!